# Newbie in MVC3 connection setup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm a real newbie in MVC3 but excited to learn. Guide me how to change connection from App_Data (DB.mdf) to MS SQL Server 2008.

MDF connection

```
<add name="MvcMusicStoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MusicStore.csdl|res://*/Models.MusicStore.ssdl|res://*/Models.MusicStore.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MvcMusicStore.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a working one from my running project:

```
<add name="CONNECTION_NAME" connectionString="data source=SQL_SERVER_IP\INSTANCE_NAME; User ID=SQL_USER_NAME; Password=YOUR_PASSWORDd;Initial catalog=DB_NAME" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

for your posted one, it may look like this:

as I can see, you are not following the MVC3 version of music store, or that's how it look for me as I've checked the PDF file of the MVC3 vesion and found that **Jon Galloway** is using the connecion string just like the one I'm using.

check out the PDF from here: http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/59112#DownloadId=197609

That's it, no other parts are required.

this is also a very very nice resource for you to find the different ways that you can do to configure your app connection string.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

From [SQL Server 2008 connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

Example:

```
<add name="NAME" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress; User ID=username; Password=password;Initial catalog=database" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

If you are going to use `Entity Framework` you need to change the provider to

```
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

And modify the `add` tag:

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=test;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```